# Template format error when I try to use join,sub and importvalue together

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use join,sub and import value together but when I try it I get malformed template error.

Here is the portion of my code:

```
 EventSourceMapping:
Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
Properties:
  EventSourceArn:
    !Join [ "/", [ !Select [0, !Split ["/", Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-stream-arn']],Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-dynamodb-name','stream','*' ] ]
  FunctionName:
    Fn::GetAtt:
    - LambdaDynamoEsConnector
    - Arn
  StartingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON
```

So I get error at this :

```
 !Join [ "/", [ !Select [0, !Split ["/", Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-stream-arn']],Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-dynamodb-name','stream','*' ] ]
```

What is wrong with what I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
EventSourceMapping: 
  Type: "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping"
  Properties: 
    EventSourceArn:
      !Join
        - "/"
        - 
          - !Select
            - 0
            - !Split
              - "/"
              - Fn::ImportValue:
                  !Sub "${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-stream-arn"
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub "${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-dynamodb-name"
          - "stream"
          - "*"
```

Since you haven't mentioned the value of `${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-stream-arn` and `${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-dynamodb-name`, I don't know what is the `EventSourceArn` you want to create, but based on your ***Join*** condition, I believe this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks now when I run it I get  Value of property EventSourceArn must be of type String. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Can you provide some sample values for `${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-stream-arn` and `${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-dynamodb-name` ? Then probably it will be easy to reproduce for me.

Comment: sure: test-test-stream-arn for and arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxx:table/* for ${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-dynamodb-name

Comment: Thanks for giving `test-test-dynamodb-name`export value. But for the other one, I get that `test-test-stream-arn` is the **ExportName**, where `${project}`=`test` and `${EnvironmentApp}`=`test`.  But what is the **ExportValue** of it? Give me a sample stream arn value which you are trying to export. Also mention what is the final `EventSourceArn` you want to create.

Comment: So if I understand your question here is the exported value:  arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:accountid:table/stg6-dynamodb-table-search/stream/2017-11-09T20:01:28.145Hope I answered correctly

Comment: Ohhh wait your answer is totally correct I had EventspurceArn repeated